# How to show color gradient on scatter plot in matlab?

Tags: matlab, visualization, matlab-figure, scatter

I have a scatter plot that will overlay several sets of data.  Each set of data currently displays as the next color in the default colormap.  This is my code right now:

```
figure
hold on
for i=1:10
   scatter(RunRawArea(i,:), RunRawNetLength(i,:));
end
hold off
```

What i would like is to color code each set of data (indexed by i) to be the next color on a gradient.  For example, the data for i=1 would be blue, i=5 would be purple, and i=10 would be red.

How could I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You should add another parameter to `scatter` - called `CData`

https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/scatter.html

> Description: scatter(x,y) creates a scatter plot with circles
>   at the locations specified by the vectors x and y. This type of graph
>   is also known as a bubble plot.

In your example:

```
figure
hold on
colorVec = linspace(1,0, size(RunRawNetLength,1));
colorVec = transpose(colorVec);
colorVec = repmat(colorVec,[1 3]);
for i=1:10
   scatter(RunRawArea(i,:), RunRawNetLength(i,:),'CData', colorVec );
end
hold off
```

Comment: For anyone looking for this in 2017 and finding that the link doesn't work anymore: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/scatter.html

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1:**

You can vectorize your data, so you don't need a loop and than add a color by series:

```
% specify your color map:
colorCode = lines(size(RunRawNetLength,1)); % or any other colormap...
% define the correct color for each series:
coloVev = repmat(colorCode,size(RunRawNetLength,1),1);
% plot it all at once without a loop:
scatter(RunRawArea(:),RunRawNetLength(:),[],coloVev)
```

**Method 2:**

If you have the Statistics and Machine Learning Toolbox you can also do this with [`gscatter`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/gscatter.html):

```
% define the series of data:
group = repmat(1:size(RunRawNetLength,1),1,size(RunRawNetLength,1));
% plot it all at once without a loop:
gscatter(RunRawArea(:),RunRawNetLength(:),group,colorCode);
```

if your colormap has not enough colors for all the series, then the function loops over and start from the first one.

**Result:**

In both cases the result for some random data will be (the main difference is that `gscatter` fill the data points and add the legend by default):

[image: gscatter demo]

*Note that I used the colormap `lines` which has only 7 entries, so in this example with 10 series it repeats itself.*